# Blog pages show at most unrecognized by code

Tags: archives

This is the code I use to grab my post archives and style the first post differently.  (Full code linked.)

This code does not seem to be recognizing the "Blog pages show at most" setting under Settings > Reading.  I am unsure why.  Help is appreciated!

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $postvariable++; /* count the posts */ ?>

<!-- Begin: Post formats -->
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?><?php } ?>
<?php if ($postvariable == 1)
echo '<div class="excerpt first-post">';
else echo '<div class="excerpt">'; ; ?>
```

http://snippi.com/s/73cz9fo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set your post counter outside your loop first before it will work. If you turn debugging on, you will get an undefined variable notice. You can do something like this just outside your loop before the loop starts

```
$postvariable = 1;
```

Alternatively you can make use of the build-in post counter, `$wp_query->current_post`. It starts counting at 0, so to target the firts post, you can do

```
if( 0 == $wp_query->current_post ) {
    //do something for first post
}
```